# Why does link title no longer wrap after changes using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, title

I am changing a link title using JavaScript.

```
document.getElementById("collapse_frame").title="Expand .. & # 0 1 3 ;[Alt] (Shift) X";
```

The title was wrapping using & # 0 1 3 ; before the change, so I used the same for the new title, but it no longer wraps.

Answer (score 2):

`&#013;` is how you write a carriage return in HTML.

You aren't writing HTML. You are writing JavaScript.

The equivalent is `\r`.